# Merge information from Excel to Notepad++

Tags: excel, notepad++

I am having a little problem. While the technique I am currently using is somewhat workable, it certainly is not the fastest or easiest way to do things. I have attached a picture of the excel file, and the desired result below.

### Scenario:

I have an excel file with multiple products. Say product name HX44 can fit 100,000 vehicles, in the Excel file, Column A has all the compatible vehicles, and column 2 has the same product name repeated for each car. I am trying to merge all of column A for that specified product, so it's all on one line, instead of multiple lines.

### Tedious solution tried:

Excel limits this by only allowing 8000 characters per cell, so what I have done is filtered in Excel via product, then copying the vehicle list to NotePad++, then highlighting the copied text, and selecting "remove unnecessary blank and EOL", which then concatenates all the information onto 1 row. I then can copy my cells from B2-> onwards into Notepad++, giving me the generated result below (if you copy this into Notepad++ or Notepad, it'll come onto one line.

Dilemma I am having is that I have a few million rows of excel files and was wondering whether there's a way to have this done in a much faster way, i.e. is there a tool to migrate this information from Excel to Notepad++?

### Expected Result:

> Root|Home|PRODUCTS|Filtration|MERCEDES-BENZ|240D|2.4L DIESEL|1983|| Root|Home|PRODUCTS|Filtration|MERCEDES-BENZ|300CD|3.0L DIESEL|1983|| Root|Home|PRODUCTS|Filtration|MERCEDES-BENZ|300D|3.0L DIESEL|1983|| Root|Home|PRODUCTS|Filtration|MERCEDES-BENZ|300TD|3.0L DIESEL|1983|| Root|Home|PRODUCTS|Filtration|MERCEDES-BENZ|240D|2.4L DIESEL|1982|| Root|Home|PRODUCTS|Filtration|MERCEDES-BENZ|300D|3.0L DIESEL|1982|| Root|Home|PRODUCTS|Filtration|MERCEDES-BENZ|300TD|3.0L DIESEL|1982|| Root|Home|PRODUCTS|Filtration|MERCEDES-BENZ|240D|2.4L DIESEL|1981|| Root|Home|PRODUCTS|Filtration|MERCEDES-BENZ|300CD|3.0L DIESEL|1981|| Root|Home|PRODUCTS|Filtration|MERCEDES-BENZ|300D|3.0L DIESEL|1981|| Root|Home|PRODUCTS|Filtration|MERCEDES-BENZ|300TD|3.0L DIESEL|1981|| Root|Home|PRODUCTS|Filtration|MERCEDES-BENZ|240D|2.4L DIESEL|1980|| Root|Home|PRODUCTS|Filtration|MERCEDES-BENZ|300CD|3.0L DIESEL|1980|| Root|Home|PRODUCTS|Filtration|MERCEDES-BENZ|300D|3.0L DIESEL|1980|| Root|Home|PRODUCTS|Filtration|MERCEDES-BENZ|240D|2.4L DIESEL|1979|| Root|Home|PRODUCTS|Filtration|MERCEDES-BENZ|240D|2.4L DIESEL|1978|| Root|Home|PRODUCTS|Filtration|MERCEDES-BENZ|240D|2.4L DIESEL|1977|| Root|Home|PRODUCTS|Filtration|MERCEDES-BENZ|300D|3.0L DIESEL|1977|| Root|Home|PRODUCTS|Filtration|MERCEDES-BENZ|280|2.8L |1976|| Root|Home|PRODUCTS|Filtration|MERCEDES-BENZ|280C|2.8L |1976|| Root|Home|PRODUCTS|Filtration|MERCEDES-BENZ|280S|2.8L |1976|| Root|Home|PRODUCTS|Filtration|MERCEDES-BENZ|280|2.8L |1975|| Root|Home|PRODUCTS|Filtration|MERCEDES-BENZ|280C|2.8L |1975|| Root|Home|PRODUCTS|Filtration|MERCEDES-BENZ|280S|2.8L |1975||;Oil Filter HX 45•;HX 45•;As a leading global development partner for the automotive and engine industry, MAHLE offers unique systems competence in the areas of engine systems, filtration, electrics/mechatronics, and thermal management. The MAHLE Group ranks among the top three systems suppliers worldwide for mobile applications in these sectors.In the original equipment industry, MAHLE provides technologically innovative solutions for automotive, commercial vehicle, machinery, and other industrial applications. The Aftermarket business unit also serves the independent parts market with MAHLE products in OE quality.>MAHLE has a local presence in all major world markets. In 2014, some 66,000 employees at approximately 150 production locations are expected to generate sales of around EUR ten billion. At ten major research and development centers in Germany, Great Britain, the USA, Brazil, Japan, China, and India, more than 4,500 development engineers and technicians are working on forward-looking concepts, products, and systems.;10;10;

[Excel file example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/879qX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your excel file as `CSV (Comma delimited)` or `Text (Tab delimited)`. That will then save the entire file to a format that is easy to work with in Notepad++ or other text-based tools. Excel can then open either type of file after it has been modified.

Comment: This wouldnt work. Reason is that there are 100,000 lines of information, but within those 100,000 lines of information, theres only 140 unique products. Once i convert to CSV or TXT, itll simply convert every row into comma delimited, which ultimately is still 100,000 rows of information. What I am trying to archieve is having those 140 unique products, with the associated vehicles concatenated in one row.

i.e. example i provided above, i would expect only 140 rows of that information.
so essentially something like this: a1:a6000 contentated;product id;product name;description;quantity;price

Comment: You want unique products, right? In Notepad++, select everything, then choose TextFX > TextFX Tools > Sort lines (case sensitive). If your data is pre-sorted in excel, that might speed things up. You will have to remove the last line though and then add it back in. This isn't the most efficient way to process large amounts of data, but since I don't know where your excel data is coming from and what you can do there, or what programming languages you are familiar with, this is the best I can suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You say you want them all on one line, but your Expected Results shows them on separate lines. I'll assume you want them all on one line.

```
Sub MakeTextFile()

    Dim vaData As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim aCar() As String, lCarCnt As Long
    Dim aLine() As String, lLineCnt As Long
    Dim sPart As String
    Dim sFile As String, lFile As String

    'Read in all the data
    vaData = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value

    'Establish the first part
    sPart = vaData(1, 3)
    For i = LBound(vaData, 1) To UBound(vaData, 1)
        'if it's a new part make a line for the text file
        If vaData(i, 3) <> sPart Then AddToLine aLine, lLineCnt, lCarCnt, sPart, vaData, aCar, i

        'add the current car to the car array
        lCarCnt = lCarCnt + 1
        ReDim Preserve aCar(1 To lCarCnt)
        aCar(lCarCnt) = vaData(i, 1)

    Next i

    'the last line won't be a change in part, so add the line here
    AddToLine aLine, lLineCnt, lCarCnt, sPart, vaData, aCar, i - 1

    'write the lines to a file
    sFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "PartsCars.txt"
    lFile = FreeFile
    Open sFile For Output As lFile
    Print #lFile, Join(aLine, vbNewLine)
    Close lFile

End Sub

Public Sub AddToLine(ByRef aLine() As String, ByRef lLineCnt As Long, ByRef lCarCnt As Long, ByRef sPart As String, ByRef vaData As Variant, ByRef aCar() As String, ByVal i As Long)

    'write all the cars plus selected info (cols 2, 3, 4) to the line
    lLineCnt = lLineCnt + 1
    ReDim Preserve aLine(1 To lLineCnt)
    aLine(lLineCnt) = Join(aCar, vbNullString) & vaData(i - 1, 2) & vaData(i - 1, 3) & vaData(i - 1, 4)
    ReDim aCar(1 To 1) 'reinitialize Car array
    lCarCnt = 0
    sPart = vaData(i, 3) 'set the new part

End Sub
```